# Кнопка удаления в HTML

Tags: html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать кнопку, чтобы она удаляла элемент в HTML.

**ТЕРАФЛЮ**

```
<p>ТераФлю - это порошок для приготовления раствора, который&nbsp;
    устраняет симптомы "простуды". Входящие в состав активные вещества&nbsp; оказывают жаропонижающее, анальгезирующее, сосудосуживающее действие .
    Такой комплексный подход позволяет ускорить выздоровление и уменьшить симптомы болезни. Порошок имеет приятный лимонный вкус, что делает его прием более комфортным.
    Удобная упаковка позволяет брать порошки с собой и применять при первых признаках заболевания.</p> <button>Удалить</button>
```

Comment: Какой элемент? Где удаляла?

Comment: Например параграф в html файле

Comment: Вот вставьте пример в вопрос, чтобы было понятно тому, кто читает, а то нахватаете минусов.

Comment: <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>ТЕРАФЛЮ</strong></p>
<p>ТераФлю - это порошок для приготовления раствора, который&nbsp; устраняет симптомы "простуды". Входящие в состав активные вещества&nbsp; оказывают жаропонижающее, анальгезирующее, сосудосуживающее действие .
    </p>
<button>Удалить</button>

Comment: В вопрос вставьте, а не в комментарии. Там кнопка [edit] есть.

Comment: если совсем коротко - `<onclick='document.getElementById("родитель терафлюшного параграфа").remuveChild(document.getElementById("сам параграф"));'>` как то так... хочется полее подробное решение? воткни в топик полностью всю верстку, а не кусок. p.s. если на странице предполагается взаимодействие js с html обязательно давайте своим тегам id'ы и class'ы или хотя бы только class'ы, по id'ам проще всего ориентироваться в js

Answer (score 2):

На JavaScript, например, можно так

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach((el) => {
    el.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <strong>ТЕРАФЛЮ</strong>
</p>
<p>
  ТераФлю - это порошок для приготовления раствора, который устраняет симптомы "простуды".
  Входящие в состав активные вещества оказывают жаропонижающее, анальгезирующее, сосудосуживающее действие.
</p>
<button>Удалить</button>
```